# $R$-recursion for the A307389

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

- Let $a(n)$ be [A307389](https://oeis.org/A307389) i.e. an integer sequence such that its exponential generating function $A(x)$ satisfies
  $$
  A(x)=\exp\left(\frac{\exp(2x)-2\exp(x)+2x+1}{2}\right)
  $$
  The sequence begins with
  $$
  1, 1, 2, 7, 29, 136, 737, 4537, 30914, 229831, 1850717, 16036912, 148573889, 1463520241
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R(n,q) = (q+1)R(n-1,q) - R(n-1,q+1) + R(n-1,q+2), \\
  R(0,q) = 1
  $$

I conjecture that $$R(n, 0) = a(n).$$

Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:

```
a_upto(n) = my(t='t+O('t^(n+1))); Vec(serlaplace(exp((exp(2*t)-2*exp(t)+2*t+1)/2)))
R_upto(n) = my(v1, v2, v3); v1 = vector(2*n + 1, i, 1); v2 = v1; v3 = vector(n + 1, i, 0); v3[1] = 1; for(i = 1, n, for(q = 0, 2*(n - i), v2[q + 1] = (q + 1) * v1[q + 1] - v1[q + 2] + v1[q + 3]); v1 = v2; v3[i + 1] = v1[1]); v3
test(n) = R_upto(n) == a_upto(n)
```

Is there a way to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
\begin{equation*}
A(x,q) = e^{qx}A(x)=e^{(q+1)x+(e^x-1)^2/2}
\end{equation*}
and define $a(n,q)$ by
\begin{equation*}
A(x,q) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n,q) \frac{x^n}{n!}.
\end{equation*}
Then $a(n,0) = a(n)$.
We find that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\ }{dx}A(x,q)&=\bigl((q+1) - e^x +e^{2x}) A(x,q)\\
  &=(q+1)A(x,q) -A(x,q+1) +A(x,q+2).
\end{align*}
Equating coefficients of $x^{n-1}/(n-1)!$ for $n\ge 1$ gives
\begin{equation*}
a(n,q) = (q+1)a(n-1,q) -a(n-1,q+1) + a(n-1, q+2).
\end{equation*}
Since $a(0,q)=1$, it follows that $R(n,q) = a(n,q)$, and in particular,
$R(n,0)=a(n,0)=a(n)$.